# Can't install wxPython by using pip on a Python 3.10.11 installation

Tags: python3, pip

I've recently installed Python 3.10.11 on openSuSE 15.4 from source as the Python version, which comes with SuSE, had proved too old (3.6). Now I need to add several modules, of which one is `wxPython>=4.1.1`, as stated in the requirement of the app (`displaycal-python3`) I'd like to set up. Installing `wxPython`…

```sh
(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3  ‹develop*› 
             ╰─➤  pip install wxPython                                                  1 ↵
```

…did not succeed due to a strange error:

```sh
      Setting top to                            : /tmp/pip-install-jrczxi29/wxpython_b642a422084843e69dbbbbd05cef236e
      Setting out to                            : /tmp/pip-install-jrczxi29/wxpython_b642a422084843e69dbbbbd05cef236e/build/waf/3.10/gtk3
      Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)           : /usr/bin/gcc
      Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)         : /usr/bin/g++
      Checking for program 'python'             : /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python
      Checking for python version >= 3.7.0      : 3.10.11
      python-config                             : not found
      Checking for library python3.10 in LIBDIR : yes
      Checking for header Python.h              : Distutils not installed? Broken python installation? Get python-config now!
      The configuration failed
      (complete log in /tmp/pip-install-jrczxi29/wxpython_b642a422084843e69dbbbbd05cef236e/build/waf/3.10/gtk3/config.log)
      Command '"/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python" /tmp/pip-install-jrczxi29/wxpython_b642a422084843e69dbbbbd05cef236e/bin/waf-2.0.24 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-jrczxi29/wxpython_b642a422084843e69dbbbbd05cef236e/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python" --out=build/waf/3.10/gtk3 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
      Finished command: build_py (0m1.50s)
      Finished command: build (1m22.114s)
      Command '"/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython
  Running setup.py clean for wxPython
Failed to build wxPython
ERROR: Could not build wheels for wxPython, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I don't know why `pip` can't find `python-config`, as it's already on my machine:

```sh
(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3  ‹develop*› 
             ╰─➤  pip install python-config                                             1 ↵
Requirement already satisfied: python-config in /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.2)
```

Following a hint from an older issue [Distutils can't find Python.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103991/distutils-cant-find-python-h):

```sh
(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3  ‹develop*› 
             ╰─➤  export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include:C_INCLUDE_PATH

(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3  ‹develop*› 
             ╰─➤  export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include:CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

…did not help either. So: How can I tell `pip` where `Python.h` lies (in fact, it's situated in `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include`) and overcome this build error?

**UPDATE:** I've found out that the `pip.conf` file was missing in with virtual environment I'm using. So I wrote one:

```ini
[global]
default-timeout = 60
respect-virtualenv = true
download-cache = /tmp
log-file = /tmp/pip-log.txt
include-dirs = /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include/cpython:/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include
```

…and ran the installtation command for a second time. But now I got an error without a message or even a trace:

```sh
(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3  ‹develop*› 
             ╰─➤  pip install wxPython                                                  1 ↵
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wxPython) (9.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wxPython) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wxPython) (1.24.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: wxPython
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for wxPython (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython
  Running setup.py clean for wxPython
Failed to build wxPython
ERROR: Could not build wheels for wxPython, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Further investigations led to such an error message:

```
  self.initialize_options()
error: can't copy '/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3/DisplayCAL/../dist/net.displaycal.DisplayCAL.appdata.xml': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

**UPDATE #2:**
The XML filed mentioned in the message does exist, but in another directory: `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/displaycal-py3/misc` So I created a symlink and re-ran `pip`. The XML file was not an issue anymore, but the missing `Python.h` is still there:

```sh
  python-config                             : /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python-config
  Checking for library python3.10 in LIBDIR : yes
  Checking for header Python.h              : Distutils not installed? Broken python installation? Get python-config now!
  The configuration failed
```

Python.h of course does exist in my Python installation: `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include`

What does NOT help, is to pass the path to the header files to the venv acticator — like this:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin  
╰─➤  source activate --cflags="-I/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include"
```

So: How do I tell `pip`, `wheel`, venv or whoever to add `/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/Include` to the include file path??

Answer (score 0):

Check these threads, I had this issue too. Hopefully you've solved it by now but just in case:

https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2297
https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1599647177-Problem-and-Solution-for-Installing-wxPython-on-Ubuntu-20-04

I was running wsl Ubuntu 22.04 Python 3.11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1205411)

Comment: Nah, sorry! The forum entries you linked describe different issues, not mine.